# How to see if mouse is down or screen is touched in event?

Tags: godot

I see that I can use `event.is_pressed()` to check for when a click (and I'm assuming, a tap) has occurred. But any additional motion while the LMB (left mouse button) is still down, doesn't equal `true` using `is_pressed()`

Here's a block of code I'm using for this test:

```
func _input(event):
    var tilemap = find_node("TileMap")
    if(event.is_pressed()):
        tiles.highlight(event.position)
```

When I actually click, `tiles.highlight()` is called, but while I move the mouse with LMB still down, it doesn't call `tiles.highlight()`. Is there a different function I need to use here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use polling to see if the mouse button is being held down.

```
func _ready():
    set_process(true)

func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_mouse_button_pressed(1):  # Left mouse button.
        print('Left mouse button pressed. ', get_viewport().get_mouse_position())
```

Otherwise, you can set a variable, for example `mouse_button_pressed`, to `true` or `false` in the `_input` function when a mouse button is pressed or released and then check it in the `_process` function:

```
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.is_pressed():  # Mouse button down.
            mouse_button_pressed = true
        elif not event.is_pressed():  # Mouse button released.
            mouse_button_pressed = false

func _process(delta):
    if mouse_button_pressed: 
        print('Left mouse button pressed. ', get_viewport().get_mouse_position())
```

Comment: I've read that a left mouse button event is the same as a touch event, but better research this yourself, since I can't test this.